# find files containing "Emacs"

Tags: dired, find-dired, find

I employed `find` within the current directory to find files containing "emacs"

```
$ find . -type f -iname "*emacs*" | nl | tail -3
    34  ./sources/tech/20190916 The Emacs Series Exploring ts.el.md
    35  ./sources/tech/20200311 What you need to know about variables in Emacs.md
    36  ./sources/tech/20191009 The Emacs Series ht.el- The Hash Table Library for Emacs.md
```

Get a result of 36 files,

When come to Emacs "find-name-dired", but find only one file

```
2637215      8 -rw-rw-r--   1 me   me       7708 Dec 19 20:48 sources/tech/20191218\ Emacs\ for\ Vim\ users-\ Getting\ started\ with\ the\ Spacemacs\ text\ editor.md
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## tl;dr

Do you get the expected behavior under `emacs -Q`? It's possible you've disabled case-insensitivity.

## Long answer

Without knowing your arguments to `find-name-dired` (you should add them to your question) it's hard to say. If you included the double quotes, Emacs will escape them and `find` will look for files that include them. Based on your output that doesn't seem to be the case. It's possible you've run into a case-sensitivity issue and you triggered on the "emacs" in "Spacemacs", not the "emacs" in "...Emacs for Vim...".

(The following is based on Emacs 26.2)

By default (ie under `emacs -Q`) `find-name-dired` is case insensitive, but that's configurable. From the documentation of `find-name-dired` (via `Ctrl-H f find-name-dired RET`):

```
find-name-dired is an interactive autoloaded Lisp function in
‘find-dired.el’.

(find-name-dired DIR PATTERN)

Search DIR recursively for files matching the globbing pattern PATTERN,
and run Dired on those files.
PATTERN is a shell wildcard (not an Emacs regexp) and need not be quoted.
The default command run (after changing into DIR) is

    find . -name 'PATTERN' -ls

See ‘find-name-arg’ to customize the arguments.
```

If we follow the docs to `find-name-arg`, we find:

```
find-name-arg is a variable defined in ‘find-dired.el’.
Its value is "-iname"

Documentation:
Argument used to specify file name pattern.
If ‘read-file-name-completion-ignore-case’ is non-nil, -iname is used so that
find also ignores case.  Otherwise, -name is used.

You can customize this variable.

This variable was introduced, or its default value was changed, in
version 22.2 of Emacs.
```

And again to `read-file-name-completion-ignore-case`:

```
read-file-name-completion-ignore-case is a variable defined in ‘minibuffer.el’.
Its value is t

Documentation:
Non-nil means when reading a file name completion ignores case.

You can customize this variable.

This variable was introduced, or its default value was changed, in
version 22.1 of Emacs.
```

So, if your `find-name-arg` is not "-iname" and/or your `read-file-name-completion-ignore-case` is `nil`, `find-name-dired` will be case sensitive. Check your init files (and `custom.el`), to find when these variables have been changed. Also, you can use `find-dired` to set the arguments to `find` yourself.

Comment: The default value of read-file-name-completion-ignore-case depends on the operating system, it's t when the default file system is not case sensitive (ms-dos, windows-nt, darwin, cygwin) (deleted and reposted comment, the original one had spelling errors)